# Ext chart autosize

Tags: extjs, charts

I'm trying to make a chart(ext 4.1):

```
    var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    width: 280,
    height: 230,
    animate: true,
    autoSize: true,
    shadow: true,
    store: storeChart2,
    renderTo: 'chart2',
    legend: {
//position: 'right'
    },
    theme: 'Base:gradients',
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        field: 'data',
        showInLegend: false,
        highlight: {
          segment: {
            margin: 20
          }
        },
         tips: {
                  trackMouse: true,
          width: 100,
                  renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                    this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + Math.round(all * storeItem.get('data') / 100) +' ('+ Math.round(storeItem.get('data') / 100 * 100) + '%)');
                  }
                },
        label: {
            field: 'name',
            display: 'rotate',
            contrast: true,
            font: '12px Arial'
        }
    }]
});
```

AutoSize: true, - don't work. In Chrome console:

```
Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute width="-Infinity"
Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute height="-Infinity"
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a property,

> minimum: 0

Please refer this [post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?159196-getting-error-as-Error-Invalid-value-for-lt-rect-gt-attribute-y-quot-Infinity-quot-on-chart&p=878711&viewfull=1#post878711)